# Inserting JSON information in Flutter Cards?

Tags: arrays, json, widget, flutter

How do I supply `flutter` Card Widgets with JSON information the way I would with a tableView Controller in Swift; which is feed various arrays with titles, images, descriptions, e.g. and index off each item?

**** UPDATE with JSON decode Code

```
var httpClient = createHttpClient();
    var response = await httpClient.read(url);
    String data = JSON.decode(response);
    Map items = JSON.decode(data);
    Map<String, dynamic> decoded = new JsonCodec().decode(data);
    for (String key in decoded.keys) {
      print("Key $key contains: ${decoded[key]}");
```

I've added the above code and now I'm getting this error.  Please provide any ideas on how to fix.  BTW...  This is coming from a YouTube ResponseList

```
type '_InternalLinkedHashMap<String, dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'String' of 'data' where
      _InternalLinkedHashMap is from dart:collection
      String is from dart:core
      String is from dart:core
```

Answer (score 1):

1. Retrieve the data as a `String` in whatever method you choose (File I/O, Web)
2. Decode it to a map with [JSON.decode](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/dart-convert/dart-convert-library.html). After, I'd recommend you construct a model object with the map but this is not necessary.
3. Supply the data to a Widget that reads said data.

Comment: What is the best way to serialize?  i.e.  When you a dictionary of "titles" in "items" in "snippets"

Comment: Please review the updated code and error.  Please note that `Map items` is not being used but throws a similar error.